# Unity object won't look at target

Tags: unity, c#

I have a box in Unity that I want to turn to face in a direction. I tried to use `Transform.lookAt()` and `Transform.rotation` but neither seem to work. Here are my code examples for both lookAt and rotation.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    float mouseX;
    float mouseY;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState =  CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {  
        mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, transform.rotation.z);
        transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, mouseX-mouseY, 0);
        
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    float mouseX;
    float mouseY;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState =  CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {  
        mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, transform.rotation.z);
        transform.LookAt(mousePosition, Vector3.forward);
    }
}
```

Here is what the scene looks like in unity
[image]

I am trying to make the cube turn on the z axis towards the mouse pointer and then move towards it.

Comment: The Z axis in this image is the blue line pointing toward the back right. Are you sure you don't mean the Y axis (vertical, green)?

Comment: yes I meant the Z axis

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I figured it out. In the update method I had to add to the mouseX and mouseY instead of setting them.

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    float mouseX = 0;
    float mouseY = 0;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

void Update()
    {
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        mouseY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0);
        transform.LookAt(mousePosition, Vector3.left);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward/100);
    }
}
```

I tried this and it worked like I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

This code fundamentally misunderstands the different coordinate systems it's attempting to bodge together.

- `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");` returns the *change* in the mouse's screen position (in the horizontal direction, or vertical for "Mouse Y") since the previous frame, measured in *pixels*.
- `transform.rotation` and `new Quaternion` expect a unit quaternion: a vector in a four dimensional space with three imaginary components and one real component, whose squares sum to one. This has no meaning as a position in 3D space.
- `transform.LookAt` expects a position in world space as its first argument (measured in world units), and an upward direction as its second argument.

So this code is meaningless gobbledygook:

```
mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(
              mouseX /* displacement in screen pixels */,
              mouseY /* displacement in screen pixels */,
              transform.rotation.z /* imaginary number, 
              sine of half of rotation angle
              times z component of rotation axis*/
);

transform.LookAt(
               mousePosition /* position in the world? Definitely not!*/,
               Vector3.forward
 );
```

None of the three inputs you've passed to the `Vector3` constructor represent positions, distances, or even directions in world space.

It sounds like you want to project the mouse cursor onto the horizontal plane, and rotate to face that. We can do that easily:

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{  
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {  
        // Get the position of the mouse on the screen, in pixels.
        Vector2 screenPosition = Input.mousePosition;

        // Cast this point through the camera viewpoint/projection
        // to form a ray shooting through world space.
        Ray worldRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(screenPosition);

        // Form a horizontal plane through this object's origin.
        Plane worldPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);

        // Check if the ray from the cursor hits this plane.
        // If not, skip it.
        if (worldPlane.Raycast(worldRay, out float distance) {

            // If we got a hit, get the world space coordinates
            // of the point on the plane where the cursor ray hits.
            var worldPosition = worldRay.GetPoint(distance);
 
            // Rotate to look toward that point.
            transform.LookAt(worldPosition);
        }
    }
}
```